# Calling onclick from options in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a dropdown and added a onclick="*function name*" to each of the options but however on selecting those options from the dropdown I am unable to get any response
This is the code that i have tried using:

```
        <span onclick="myfunc('demo')">Sports</span>
        <select name="sports">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="cricket" onclick="myfunc('cricket')">Cricket</option>
            <option value="football" onclick="myfunc('football')">Football</option>
            <option value="volleyball" onclick="myfunc('volleyball')">Volleyball</option>
            <option value="basketball" onclick="myfunc('basketball')">Basketball</option>
            <option value="ttenis" onclick="myfunc('ttennis')">Table Tennis</option>
            <option value="athletics" onclick="myfunc('atletics')">Athletics</option>
        </select>

  function myfunc(ft){
    console.log(ft);
  }
```

My only response is when I click the span i.e.Sports, and I get 'demo displayed in the output.

Comment: Can you post an example online please

Answer (score 0):

You may use change event to handle your each item. Please follow below code as your need

```
       <select id="ddlSportsItems" name="sports">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="1">Cricket</option>
            <option value="2">Football</option>
            <option value="3">Volleyball</option>
            <option value="4">Basketball</option>
            <option value="5">Table Tennis</option>
            <option value="6">Athletics</option>
        </select>

$('#ddlSportsItems').change(function() 
{ 
    var selectedValue = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());

    switch(selectedValue){
        case 1:
            Cricket();
            break;
        case 2:
            Football();
            break;
        //etc... 
        default:
            alert("catch default");
            break;
    }
});

function Cricket(){
    alert("do your require stuff");    
}

function Football(){
    alert("do your require stuff");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in javascript:

```
       <select name="sports" onchange="myFunc(this)">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
            <option value="football">Football</option>
            <option value="volleyball">Volleyball</option>
            <option value="basketball">Basketball</option>
            <option value="ttenis">Table Tennis</option>
            <option value="athletics">Athletics</option>
        </select>

        <script>
         function myFunc(select){
           console.log(select.value);
         }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to write this would be :

```js
function myfunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
    if (selectedValue === 'cricket') {
        alert("Cricket");
        //Write your code for cricket
    }
    else if (selectedValue === 'football') {
        alert("Football");
    }
    else if (selectedValue === 'volleyball') {
        alert("Volleyball");
    }
    else if (selectedValue === 'basketball') {
        alert("BasketBall")
    
    }
    else if (selectedValue === 'ttenis') {
      alert("Table Tennis");
    }
    else if (selectedValue === 'athletics') {
      alert("Athletics");
    }
}
```

```html
<span>Sports:</span>
        <select id="selectBox" name="sports" onchange="myfunc();">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
            <option value="football">Football</option>
            <option value="volleyball">Volleyball</option>
            <option value="basketball">Basketball</option>
            <option value="ttenis">Table Tennis</option>
            <option value="athletics">Athletics</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
function myfunc() {
  alert($("#selectBox").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Sports:</span>
        <select id="selectBox" name="sports" onchange="myfunc();">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
            <option value="football">Football</option>
            <option value="volleyball">Volleyball</option>
            <option value="basketball">Basketball</option>
            <option value="ttenis">Table Tennis</option>
            <option value="athletics">Athletics</option>
        </select>
```